# Stripe Webhooks always returned "Failed to connect to remote host"

Tags: laravel, strip, laravel-cashier, stripe-payments

This is my first time using Stripe and I am faced with a problem that I cannot solve. I am using Laravel Cashier with Stripe Webhooks and did everything as described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks) , and so I think that I have nothing to show in the code. No event works, I always get this error in the Stripe Webhooks logs **Failed to connect to remote host** . I am using Docker for my project and my site on HTTPS with valid SSL certificates. I even tried different internet providers, I thought there might be a problem with this, but that didn't help either. And I understand that the problem is not in the code. Can you please help me? I really need help.

And here's a picture to make everything clear.

[image]

Comment: is the webhook you have setup accessible from outside ? I use paddle, i had to use ngrok to make my site available for the webhooks to be handled.

Comment: @Tithira No, I am not using ngrok or anything like that. I think the webhooks should send a notification to the set URL, because that's what the documentation says.

Comment: What URL are you trying to send the webhooks too?

Comment: @K-sS-k, did you ever solve this issue? I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Joseph Yes, I used ngrok to generate new URL, I don't know why but I just made a big mistake, the stripe can't access my local url )))

Comment: Thank you @K-sS-k, that's solved my issue! I'll write an answer to the post to help anyone else who has this issue in the future. I just wanted to ask, when ngrok is running for me now, it says for example, "Session Expires ... 1 hour, 46 minutes". Does this automatically renew, with the same ngrok URL?

Answer (score 1):

Install ngrok (https://ngrok.com/download)

Then follow this: youtube.com/watch?v=S1uExj7mMgM&ab_channel=Twilio
to set up ngrok to forward to your localhost on the port you are listening to, eg:

```sh
ngrok http 4000
```

See the Stripe documentation on webhooks: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart